# How to force react native app to be just RTL? for both Android and iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I want to make the app starts by default in RTL,

I tried to put `[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];` in AppDelegate.m file in iOS and nothing changed it's shill LTR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write something like below

In Android you need to write below code in Android Native side onCreate method at file location MainApplication.java in the directory android/app/src/main/java/com/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME

```
I18nUtil mI18nUtil = I18nUtil.getInstance();
mI18nUtil.forceRTL(this,true);
mI18nUtil.allowRTL(this, true);
```

in iOS you need to write code in AppDelegate.m file

```
[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES]
[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] forceRTL:YES]
```

React Native Side

```
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native';

useEffect(()=>{
  I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
})
```